# Creating an NSMutabaleArray subclass in Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create an `NSMutableArray` subclass, in Swift, which supports an array literal initializer.

I can create a simple subclass:

```
class MyArray: NSMutableArray {
}
```

And initialisation works fine:

```
let arrayInstance: MyArray = MyArray()
```

However, if I try to use an array literal:

```
let arrayInstance: MyArray = ["one"]
```

It fails at runtime, `[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: method only defined for abstract class.`.

I can add this initialiser, however, as a result I also have to add the other required initialisers:

```
class MyArray: NSMutableArray {
  override init(capacity numItems: Int) {
    super.init(capacity: numItems)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  required convenience init(arrayLiteral elements: AnyObject...) {
      fatalError("init(arrayLiteral:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the second required initialiser yields the following compiler error:

> Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet

It looks like I am stuck! Can anyone suggest a way to create an `NSMutableArray` subclass that supports array literals? Otherwise it's back to Objective-C for me!

Comment: Why exactly you need an array subclass? Any why you don't use Swift arrays?

Comment: You're correct that this probably cannot be done in Swift because of how `NSMutableArray` happens to be implemented (the init's you want come from the `NSArrayCreation` category, rather than being on the class itself). If you were anyone else, I would give a lecture on not subclassing class clusters unless you deeply know what you're doing (and then still not doing it because it's crazy and always a headache), but in your case I assume you know that, and so I'm just curious why you're subclassing `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @RobNapier that is very good general advice! The reason I am subclassing `NSMutableArray` is because I want an array that is observable (as in the Observer Pattern). I've previously used this in Objective-C in order to make it easier to bind dynamic data to table views (http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/11/04/mutable-array-binding-reactivecocoa.html). Unfortunately I keep hitting road-blocks! Can't subclass Array as it is a struct, creating my own struct causes ObjC interop problems (it isn;t automatically bridged), hence this, option #3! Option #4 is write this code in ObjC ;-)

Comment: I've built something like that before. But I used HAS-A rather than IS-A. It had the same basic interface as an array, and added/removed observations as things were put into and removed. Same idea as an `NSArrayController` (which is also HAS-A, rather than IS-A). Avoided all the headaches of class clusters.

Comment: @ColinE This may be a shot in the dark but can't you add a property observer to an appropriate property of Array (say, `count`)? I think you could do that in an extension to Array, no?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not array literals, also the first initialization not works fine, you can get the "same" crash if you doing that :

```
let arrayInstance: MyArray = MyArray()
arrayInstance.count

//OR
let secondArrayInstance: MyArray = MyArray(objects: ["one"], count: 1) // method used by literals syntax
```

The problem is subclassing NSMutableArray, because it is a class cluster.
According to Apple there is little reason to do it :

> There is typically little reason to subclass NSArray. The class does
>   well what it is designed to do—maintain an ordered collection of
>   objects. But there are situations where a custom NSArray object might
>   come in handy. Here are a few possibilities:
>
> Changing how NSArray stores the elements of its collection. You might
>   do this for performance reasons or for better compatibility with
>   legacy code.
>
> Acquiring more information about what is happening to the collection
>   (for example, statistics gathering).

**Class Clusters definition**

> Class clusters are a design pattern that the Foundation framework
>   makes extensive use of. Class clusters group a number of private
>   concrete subclasses under a public abstract superclass. The grouping
>   of classes in this way simplifies the publicly visible architecture of
>   an object-oriented framework without reducing its functional richness.
>   Class clusters are based on the Abstract Factory design pattern.

**Alternatives to Subclassing NSArray**

> Before making a custom class of NSArray, investigate NSPointerArray
>   and the corresponding Core Foundation type, CFArray Reference. Because
>   NSArray and CFArray are “toll-free bridged,” you can substitute a
>   CFArray object for a NSArray object in your code (with appropriate
>   casting). Although they are corresponding types, CFArray and NSArray
>   do not have identical interfaces or implementations, and you can
>   sometimes do things with CFArray that you cannot easily do with
>   NSArray. For example, CFArray provides a set of callbacks, some of
>   which are for implementing custom retain-release behavior. If you
>   specify NULL implementations for these callbacks, you can easily get a
>   non-retaining array.
>
> If the behavior you want to add supplements that of the existing
>   class, you could write a category on NSArray. Keep in mind, however,
>   that this category will be in effect for all instances of NSArray that
>   you use, and this might have unintended consequences. Alternatively,
>   you could use composition to achieve the desired behavior.

**Subclassing NSArray**

To subclass NSArray we must overriding *count* and *objectAtIndex*: methods

> Any subclass of NSArray must override the primitive instance methods
>   count and objectAtIndex:. These methods must operate on the backing
>   store that you provide for the elements of the collection.
>
> ---
>
> In concept, an array stores a number of data items, each of which is
>   accessible by index. NSArray expresses this abstract notion through
>   its two primitive methods, count and objectAtIndex:. With these
>   methods as a base, other methods—derived methods—can be implemented;

*Static Array example*

```
class Months: NSArray {

    let months =  [ "January", "February", "March", "April",
                    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December" ]

    override var count: Int {
        get {
          return months.count
        }
    }

    override func objectAtIndex(index: Int) -> AnyObject {
        assert(index < count, "The index is out of bounds")
        return months[index]
    }
}
```

Initialization

```
let months = Months()

println("My birthday month : \(months.objectAtIndex(6))")
println("The last month of the year : \(months.lastObject)")
```

*Array with objects*

```
class MyArray: NSArray {

    var array: [AnyObject] = []

    func populateWith(#objects: [AnyObject]) {
        self.array = objects
    }

    override var count: Int {
        get {
          return array.count
        }
    }

    override func objectAtIndex(index: Int) -> AnyObject {

        assert(index < count, "The index is out of bounds")
        return array[index]
    }
}
```

Initialization

```
let fruits = MyArray()
fruits.populateWith(objects: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Cherry"])

println("Fruits count : \(fruits.count)")
```

**Subclassing NSMutableArray**

It's the same thing of NSArray but we must overriding these methods :

- count
- objectAtIndex:
- insertObject:atIndex:
- removeObjectAtIndex:
- addObject:
- removeLastObject
- replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:

I can add example if needed

**Conclusion**

We can subclassing NSArray in swift (only when using default initializer *init()*), but we can't (yet) use other initializers (like initWithObjects:count:).

So, I Agree with you, for now, the best solution is subclassing Class Clusters in objective-c

[Class Clusters documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4)

[NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray)

Hope that helps